MyBatis sql not return result when give 0 value
   select * from table where    
<if test="amount!= null">
  amount &gt;= #{amount, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
 </if>

When give from swagger   "amount": 0, not return result. But greater than 0 return result. How handle this.  amount column is numeric(20, 2)   default 0 not null In reguestDto this format BigDecimal. How change in mybatis retun >0 full rows. Thanks..**

Why are you specifying jdbcType=VARCHAR when the column is a NUMBER?

@MT0, i use it -- jdbcType=NUMERIC same result i get. When give 0 not return 0.00  use >=

@DEVELOPERJAVA I may not fully understand your explanation, but it should work as you expect, I think (if the amount is BigDecimal, you don't need to specify jdbcType). If you could share a small demo project on your GitHub repository, I would take a look. Here are some project templates and examples. I only have Oracle 19c, though.

@JsonProperty("amount")
private BigDecimal amount; in my dto.    select * from table where

amount >= #{amount, jdbcType=NUMERIC}
   -this my sql Use mybatis).  In swagger give {
"beginRefundAmount": 0
} In database 2 value 1 amount is -0.00, second 1.00 . When execute swagger i get just my row - 1.00. not return 0.00. How handle this- return 2 row.   @MT0
